# Wordpress replacing bloginfo with home_url?

Tags: wordpress

In my header file, I'm using Wordpress function `bloginfo` following three times:

```
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

But the theme check plugin gives me following warning:

```
bloginfo(url) was found in the file header.php. Use echo home_url() instead.
```

Can someone tell me how can I replace the that? I couldn't find any information in the function references on Wordpress website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be not in your `header.php`.

find on **all your active theme files** any reference to:

```
bloginfo('url');
```

and replace it with:

```
echo home_url();
```

Comment: yes i know, but it won't work `echo home_url(stylesheet_url);`

Comment: i say replace `bloginfo('url')` not `bloginfo('stylesheet_url')`. You must have this somewhere in your theme files.

Comment: @user1117313 - See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo for valid `bloginfo()` arguments.

Comment: this might be a bit old but in case you nee to replace `bloginfo('stylesheet_url')`, use `echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead.